# Android random crash while loading views NPE android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int) in AssetManager

Tags: android, crash

I get the following crash in multiple views, very randomly on Asus phones, OnePlus phones and some Samsung phones. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:213)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1423)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1412)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2869)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1230)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
   at com.PACKAGE_NAME.UserProductAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(UserProductAdapter.java:56)
   at com.PACKAGE_NAME.UserProductAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(UserProductAdapter.java:28)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5464)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4689)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4599)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1542)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:656)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:590)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3003)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2881)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3265)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
```

has anyone managed to sucessfully fix the issue, there is bug filed but no solution: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221193

I am using supportVersion 23.2.1 and I cannot update due to another bug with maps.

This is one example of crash but I get all kinds of other crashes in views but always hard to reproduce and always in AssetManager